# Not able to pick maven local maven repository files from gradle build

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle

I have a scenario where I need to do offline build without connecting to VPN.

Initially I run tasks like this connecting to VPN

1. gradle build (generate a jar)
2. Run task cacheToMavenLocal(Copies from .gradle folders to .m2 repository folder)
   Which is successful.

Disconnected from VPN I need to run the build task and generate a jar using local maven dependencies

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    apply from: "https://artifactory.repositoryabc.com/artifactory-repositories.gradle"

}

plugins{
    id 'maven-publish'
}



apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply from: "https://artifactory.repositoryabc.com/configs/base.gradle"

apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'
apply from: 'jar.gradle'

group = 'com.test.client'
version = common.getNextBuild(group, project.name, '1.0')

sourceCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories{
    mavenLocal()

}

task cacheToMavenLocal(type: Copy) {
    from new File(gradle.gradleUserHomeDir, 'caches/modules-2/files-2.1')
    into repositories.mavenLocal().url
    eachFile {
        List<String> parts = it.path.split('/')
        it.path = (parts[0]+ '/' + parts[1]).replace('.','/') + '/' + parts[2] + '/' + parts[4]
    }
    includeEmptyDirs false
}

publishing.publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
        from components.java
        versionMapping {
            usage('java-api') {
                fromResolutionOf('runtimeClasspath')
            }
            usage('java-runtime') {
                fromResolutionResult()
            }
        }
        artifact(sourcesJar)
        artifact(javadocJar)
    }
}
```

When I run the above It still tries to connect to the repository and fails

https://artifactory.repositoryabc.com/configs/base.gradle) , Can this be avoided and instead pick from local maven repository?